# Accessing request as global variable in webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

I am migrating over my appengine application from Pylons to webapp2.
In pylons the request and response objects are global. However, in
webapp2 they are accessed as object attributes (self.request,
self.response).

But I assume using Local module in the extras package is meant for
accessing global variables in a thread safe manner.

I'm not able to figure out how to access request object as a global
variable instead of self.request in a webapp2 app, as it would preserve my existing controller code.

I was not able to find much documentation on local module and how to use it. Other frameworks like Flask and Bottle also have global access to request using contextLocal. So, it would be a more portable code to access request object the same way in webapp2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

The registry is available at both the app level and the request level.  The previous answer dealt with the app level.

Below is code that allows you to use globals at the request level.

```
def instanceHtml():
    app = webapp2.get_app()
    try: 
        aInstance = app.request.registry[ 'instanceHtml' ]  ## retrieve previous object
        return aInstance
    except:
        aInstance = zhtml.Html()  ## instantiate whatever object you want
        app.request.registry[ 'instanceHtml' ] = aInstance  ## save object
        return aInstance
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find global request objects either. Instead I used the Registry to pass stuff around between requests. Check this out:

http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/app.html#registry